# How to ensure different html elements in a row are level?

Tags: html, css

There's an example of the problem I'm facing at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bggwoecx/4/) - I have a row with two different types of elements in it, an h2 tag, and also a span tag. I have them in the same row hoping that they appear level, however, the h2 tag appears lower on the screen than the content in the span tag(s), with the resulting undesired appearance that the elements are in different rows.

Question: is there some way to wrap or style these elements to ensure they appear on the same level? Note, in the application I'm building there is more than one span tag.

```
<div class="grid-container outline">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h2>Hello</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <span class="blah">blah</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
    .grid-container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
    /*-- our cleafix hack -- */
    .row:before, .row:after {
        content:"";
        display: table;
        clear:both;
    }
    [class*='col-'] {
        float: left;
        min-height: 1px;
        width: 16.66%;
        /*-- our gutter -- */
        padding: 12px;

    }
    .col-1 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-2 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-3 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-4 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-5 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-6 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .outline, .outline * {
        outline: 1px solid #F6A1A1;
    }
    /*-- some extra column content styling --*/
    [class*='col-'] > p {

        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: I'd start by removing any margins and padding from those inner elements.

Comment: I've done that, removed margins, added 50 px padding to one span, but not the others, neither of them are moving. When I move my cursor over the span, it highlights the padding as extending outside the borders of the row, so it's not pushing against the row for some reason.

Comment: actually padding needs to be added to col-2, not to the individual spans. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, see the comment by @j08691. Adding padding to an **inline element** will not affect it's position. When you remove the margin from the h2, the h2 and span are *"on the same level"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The h2 and span elements appear at different levels due to margin on the h2. To remove it, simply add:

```
  h2{
    margin:0px;
    }
```

Afterward if you increase the font size of the span to match the H2 they should appear level.

There's a CSS property called `flexbox` that makes it easier to space HTML elements either vertically or horizontally. CSS tricks has a comprehensive article on the subject.

Using a technique mentioned in this article: http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html, I've added the CSS class below to the parent divs of the h2 and span.

```
.vertical-container {

 height: 60px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:         flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
```

JSfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/bggwoecx/5/

Answer (score 1):

A combination line-height and height might fix this for you.  Try out the following CSS.  PS:  moved your gutter into row from class col.

```
.grid-container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
    /*-- our cleafix hack -- */
    .row:before, .row:after {
        content:"";
        display: table;
        clear:both;
        height:30px;
        padding:12px;
    }
    [class*='col-'] {
        float: left;
        min-height: 1px;
        width: 16.66%;
        /*-- our gutter -- */
        /*padding: 12px;*/

    }
    .col-1 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-2 {
        width: 33.33%;
        line-height:30px;
        height:30px;
    }
    .col-3 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-4 {
        width: 66.66%;
        line-height:30px;
    }
    .col-5 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-6 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .outline, .outline * {
        outline: 1px solid #F6A1A1;
    }
    /*-- some extra column content styling --*/
    [class*='col-'] > p {

        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

h2{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```